# Combination of matrix elements giving non-zero value (PYTHON)

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, matrix, indices

I have to evaluate the following expression, given two quite large matrices A,B and a very complicated function F:
[The mathematical expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k9rR.gif)

I was thinking if there is an  efficient way in order to first find those indices i,j that will give a non-zero element after the multiplication of the matrices, so that I avoid the quite slow 'for loops'.

**Current working code**

```
# Starting with 4 random matrices 
A = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(50,50))
B = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(50,50))
C = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(50,50))
D = np.random.randint(0,2,size=(50,50))
indices []
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[0]):
        if A[i,j] != 0:
            for k in range(B.shape[1]):
                if B[j,k] != 0:
                for l in range(C.shape[1]):
                    if A[i,j]*B[j,k]*C[k,l]*D[l,i]!=0:
                        indices.append((i,j,k,l))
print indices
```

As you can see, in order to get the indices I need I have to use nested loops (= huge computational time).

Comment: care to share your existing code? Please have a look at [mcve].

Comment: You say "multiplication of the matrices" but your expression doesn't look like matrix multiplication... Are you sure your indices are all correct?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be NO: you cannot avoid the for-loops. In order to find all the indices `ij` you need to loop through all the elements which defeats the purpose of this check. Therefore, you should go ahead and use simple array elementwise multiplication and dot product in `numpy` - it should be quite fast with for loops taken care by `numpy`.

However, if you plan on using a Python loop then the answer is YES, you can avoid them by using `numpy`, using the following pseudo-code (=hand-waving):

```
i, j = np.indices((N, M)) # CAREFUL: you may need to swap i<->j or N<->M
fs = F(i, j, z) # array of values of function F
                # for a given z over the index grid
R = np.dot(A*fs, B) # summation over j
# return R # if necessary do a summation over i: np.sum(R, axis=...)
```

If the issue is that computing `fs = F(i, j, z)` is a very slow operation, then you will have to identify elements of `A` that are zero using two loops built-in into `numpy` (so they are quite fast):

```
good = np.nonzero(A) # hidden double loop (for 2D data)
fs = np.zeros_like(A)
fs[good] = F(i[good], j[good], z) # compute F only where A != 0
```